# Bubbling up an Account hierarchy to capture top most Parent Id from query

Tags: apex, soql, query, child-to-parent

Based on some of the answers I've browsed I think this might involve 2 queries. I feel like this is probably a pretty common problem so I was hoping someone would have a quick answer or at least be able to point me to the docs that detail how this works. I briefly looked through relational queries but didn't immediately see anything relevant to this kind of bubbling so I am posing the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way of fetching a Parent Id from the Account hierarchy using SOQL. However, if you want to use some Apex, you can do it using the below snippet available in the [Inline Account Hierarchy package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016chCEAQ), where `currAcctId` is the Child Account for which you need to find the top most Parent Account.

```
while (!isTopLevelAccount) {
    acct = [select a.Id, a.ParentId From Account a where a.Id = :currAcctId limit 1];
    if (acct.ParentID != null) {
        currAcctId = acct.ParentID;
    } else {
        isTopLevelAccount = true;
    }
}
return currAcctId;
```